How to debug Support.EmailTemplateSelector implemented Apex class
I have below class to handle Email Templates dynamically.
global class CaseEmailTemplateSelector implements Support.EmailTemplateSelector {

    global ID getDefaultEmailTemplateId(ID caseId) {
        System.debug('load template!!');
        try{
        // Query the case to get the Email_Template_Name__c field
        Case c = [SELECT Email_Template_Name__c FROM Case WHERE Id = :caseId LIMIT 1];

        // Query the email template based on the Email_Template_Name__c field
        //EmailTemplate et = [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = :c.Email_Template_Name__c LIMIT 1];
        return [SELECT Id FROM EmailTemplate WHERE Name = 'Reply to Closed/Approved Case Email' LIMIT 1][0].Id;
        // Return the ID of the selected email template
        //return et != null ? et.Id : null;
        //
        }
        catch(Exception ex){
            System.debug('load template!! error '+ex);
        }
        
        return null;
    }
}

Note: I have hardcoded above existing Email template for testing purpose.
I have selected the Class accordingly in Support settings,

But it's not setting the Email template, I can select the Template manually from the Case  Email action though.
I have also set (disabled) the below,

Question 1: Is there a way to troubleshoot this Apex handler? I can't see debug lines in Dev Console.
Question 2: Any tips/suggestions if I'm missing anything here?
Thanks in advance!

I used the QuickActionDefaultsHandler instead which can be selected for Setup-> Support Settings -> Apex class for 'Enable Default Email Templates or the Default Handler for Email Action', and that worked well. Also it did create debug logs without any issues.
Example from Salesforce Documentation,
global class EmailPublisherLoader implements QuickAction.QuickActionDefaultsHandler {
    // Empty constructor
    global EmailPublisherLoader() {
    }
    
    // The main interface method
    global void onInitDefaults(QuickAction.QuickActionDefaults[] defaults) {
        QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults sendEmailDefaults = null;
    
    
        // Check if the quick action is the standard case feed Email action
        for (Integer j = 0; j < defaults.size(); j++) {
            if (defaults.get(j) instanceof QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults && 
               defaults.get(j).getTargetSObject().getSObjectType() == 
                   EmailMessage.sObjectType && 
               defaults.get(j).getActionName().equals('Case.Email') && 
               defaults.get(j).getActionType().equals('Email')) {
                   sendEmailDefaults = 
                       (QuickAction.SendEmailQuickActionDefaults)defaults.get(j);
                   break;
            }
        }
        
        if (sendEmailDefaults != null) {
            Case c = [SELECT Status, Reason FROM Case 
                      WHERE Id=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
        
            EmailMessage emailMessage = (EmailMessage)sendEmailDefaults.getTargetSObject();    
            // Set BCC address to make sure each email goes for audit
            emailMessage.BccAddress = getBccAddress(c.Reason);
            
            /* 
            Set Template related fields 
            when the In Reply To Id field is null we know the interface 
            is called on page load. Here we check if 
            there are any previous emails attached to the case and load 
            the 'New_Case_Created' or 'Automatic_Response' template.
            When the In Reply To Id field is not null we know that 
            the interface is called on click of reply/reply all 
            of an email and we load the 'Default_reply_template' template
            */
            if (sendEmailDefaults.getInReplyToId() == null) {
                Integer emailCount = [SELECT count() FROM EmailMessage 
                                      WHERE ParentId=:sendEmailDefaults.getContextId()];
                if (emailCount!= null && emailCount > 0) {
                    sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(
                        getTemplateIdHelper('Automatic_Response'));
                } else {
                    sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(
                        getTemplateIdHelper('New_Case_Created'));
                }
                sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(false);
                sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(false);
            } else {
                sendEmailDefaults.setTemplateId(
                    getTemplateIdHelper('Default_reply_template'));
                sendEmailDefaults.setInsertTemplateBody(false);
                sendEmailDefaults.setIgnoreTemplateSubject(true);
            }
        }
    }
    
    private Id getTemplateIdHelper(String templateApiName) {
        Id templateId = null;
        try {
            templateId = [select id, name from EmailTemplate 
                          where developername = : templateApiName].id;   
        } catch (Exception e) {
            system.debug('Unble to locate EmailTemplate using name: ' + 
                templateApiName + ' refer to Setup | Communications Templates ' 
                    + templateApiName);
        }
        return templateId;
    }
private String getBccAddress(String reason) {
        if (reason != null && reason.equals('Technical')) 
            { return 'support_technical@mycompany.com'; } 
        else if (reason != null && reason.equals('Billing')) 
            { return 'support_billing@mycompany.com'; } 
        else { return 'support@mycompany.com'; }
    }

    
}

